# Dynamically changing background color in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap. After researching, I understand that I can use javascript to change background color. I would like to dynamically change the background color or image of a specific container. I am using external links to the style .css files

> (example:
>   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
>
> href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap->theme.min.css">
>   ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use jQuery and do as follow :

To change the bc-image:

```
$('.YourContainer').css('background-image', 'url(../images/backgrounds/bc-image.jpg)');
```

to change the bc-color :

```
$('.YourContainer').css("background-color", "yellow");
```

don't forget to add jQuery :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

edit because probably you don't know how to use the code in an embadded script tag :

```
        <!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Demo</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
            <script src="jquery.js"></script>
            <script type='text/javascript'>

            $( document ).ready(function() {



           $('.YourContainer').css('background-image', 
             'url(../images/backgrounds/bc-image.jpg)');



           });     
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kqhoepto/)**

Comment: Would the jquery code go into a function embedded within a script tag?

Comment: make sure you call the embedded code after jquery invocation

Comment: This is what I have. I don't see colorize function being called. <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"> 
  
  function colorize() {
  console.log('got here');
   $('#check_generator').css("background-color", "red");
  }
 </script>

Comment: This is how it is called <div class="container" id = "check_generator" onload="colorize()">